# timeupdate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am creating a audio player.In the js file, I want to add the event "timeupdate" to the `<input type="range" id="track" value="0"  max="100" />` . I used jQuery. In the js file, part of the code is like these:

```
var tracktime=$('#track');
tracktime[0].timeupdate(function(){
  console.log((song.currentTime/song.duration)*100);
  tracktime[0].css('value',(song.currentTime/song.duration)*100);
});
```

But the chrome tell me that the timeupdate is not a function.

Comment: Try ``tracktime.on("timeupdate", handler)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `tracktime[0]` you're accessing the DOM element itself. When you write just `tracktime`, you're manipulating jQuery wrapped element where jQuery handles things such as even bindings for you. This let's you bind events such as:

```
tracktime.click(function(e) { ... });
```

So in jQuery this `timeupdate` event doesn't have a shortcut so you have to bind it using [.on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
tracktime.on('timeupdate', function() { 
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`timeupdate` is an event, not a function. Try this:

```
var tracktime=$('#track');
tracktime.on('timeupdate', function() {
   // ... your code ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning directly to the object, you need to use `ontimeupdate`, if you are using `addEventListener` then you would use: `tracktime[0].addEventListener('timeupdate', ...)`:

```
tracktime[0].ontimeupdate
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441309.aspx